# How to collapse other expanded rows in PrimeReact DataTable

Tags: datatable, primereact, rowexpansion

I am very new to react and wanted to handle row expand/collapse in a prime react data table. I am trying to keep only one row expanded at a time

```
const onRowToggle = ( e) => { setExpandedRows(e.data); }
```

I am using above line for that purpose.
Please help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have only one row expanded, then remove `onRowToggle` from your `DataTable` component and implement the following `onRowExpand` method

```
  onRowExpand(event) {
    setExpandedRows({ [event.data.id]: true });
  }
```

Comment: @MuditaPandey perfect! dont forget to accept answer if it helped you :)

Comment: it is working fine with expand but after expanding when i click the same one it is not collapsing back

Comment: i guess you need this `onRowCollapse(event) {
    setExpandedRows({ [event.data.id]: false});
  }`

Comment: if this is working, dont forget to accept answer. green tick, thank you

Comment: @Apostolos, Your suggested solution worked for me. This answer should be accepted.